# Enter key hit event is not getting captured in Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, gwt, keyboard, enter

When I ran my app(GWT java) using chrome browser the following code works well

```
if (event.getUnicodeCharCode() == 13)
```

But the same app ran through Firefox browser doesn't give desirable result.

I want to capture the enter event from all browser and do the same processing code.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not fire a `keypress` event for the Enter key, you have to use `keydown` or `keyup` instead (but then handle key codes, rather than character codes; fortunately they're the same for the Enter key and the LF character).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the char code look at the key code, code associated with the physical key:

```
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER)
```